# ¿Cómo puedo saber de una lista de documentos de citas, verificar que no tengan una cita a la misma hora?

Tags: javascript, nodejs

De que forma se puede verificar que una cita no se realice a la mis hora que otra. Este es el modelo de citas. ¿como verifico si ya existe una cita asignada antes de generar otra?

```
const Cita = new Schema({
  user_per: String,//Usuario
  user_rev: String,//Cliente
  start : Date,
  end : Date
}
```

Comment: Hola, tu pregunta no está del todo clara. ¿Deseas verificar si dos o más documentos tienen la misma hora de cita asignada? o por el contrario, ¿deseas verificar si ya existe una cita asignada antes de generar otra? Saludos

Comment: Asi es, es saber si la cita ya se encuentra asignada en esa hora. porfavor ayuda con la solución. @MauricioContreras

Comment: Muy bien, ¿puedes decir si usas Mongoose y MongoDB?, al parecer si, ya que el Esquema que publicas parece indicar eso. Trata de ser lo más claro posible. ¿Cómo estás realizando la búsqueda en la base de datos? Saludos